# Virtual Box for everyday use?

Tags: virtual-machine

I was just thinking about how nice virtual machines are...and how even "rebooting" is less painful, because at the very least, you don't have to wait for your physical computer to turn off and on with all the mobo shannanigans at the start... so, what if I ran *everything* in a virtual machine? Then I wouldn't really need a primary OS, I just need something than can run VirtualBox or what have you. So what's the lightest weight OS I could install, that supports a good virtual machine?

Comment: Sloooooooooooooowww!
Other than that (and no graphics acceleration), go for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an enterprise linux like CentOS (libvirt, kvm, xen) or Debian with XEN. This way you can run your system virtually... however, you won't ever achieve the same performance. (Whether it be IO, graphical, etc. XEN/qemu/kvm is close to the IO perf, but still not the same. You won't have Graphical accel (normal) in your box, etc etc.)
Or you can also install Virtualbox, not like it would be better. You have to close the VMs occasionally, update VBox, update your system, reboot, close the VMs, start them..bla bla. Much more inconvenient.

Comment: By the way the thing you want is called "Thin Client" and they use it at big corporations. (They run a huge server with large capacity and send out all the stuff using cables. So basically people just WATCH the screen, and interact with the server. Its like a terminal or something like that. However, its not really an efficient stuff for home. Its ok for office but nothing else I guess.)

Comment: Oh...nevermind then. So much for that idea :D Running Ubuntu 10.04 in virtualbox, haven't had any speed issues, but I haven't exactly been doing any intensive stuff on it :D